# Implementing Find References in Visual Studio 2010 Language Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, languageservice

I'm implementing a Visual Studio Language Service for a custom scripting language.  I've managed to implement syntax highlighting, error checking, code completion,  and "Go To Definition".  I am having trouble figuring out how to hook in to the "Find All References" menu option (or even get it to display at this point).

**Can anyone point me to a useful resource for implementing "Find All References" functionality in Visual Studio for a custom language?**  I've tried Googling for any information on it, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Is your extension currently open source? I'm curious which language service framework, if any, you are using for the other features.

Comment: It is an internal project I am working on at my company to add support for an internal scripting language.  I created a `VSPackage` from scratch and used ANTLR4 for the parser/lexer.  Syntax highlighting is done by my implementation of the `IScanner` interface.  Error checking is performed in implementations of the `IParseTreeListener` interface, with hooks to an implementation of the `IErrorHandler` interface for displaying them in the GUI.  "Go To Defintion" is in an implementation of the `AuthoringScope` class (and I believe code-completion is handled there as well).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there are multiple locations where Find All References can be invoked. The primary ones are:

1. By right clicking on a node in Class View.
2. By right clicking within the text editor.

Others include:

1. The Call Hierarchy

#### Getting Started

In the ideal implementation, you'll have an implementation of [`IVsSimpleLibrary2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssimplelibrary2.aspx) which integrates support for your language into the Class View and Object Browser windows. The implementation of Find All References centers around the [`IVsFindSymbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsfindsymbol.aspx) interface, which is provided by Visual Studio. Your code handles the relevant searches in the implementation of [`IVsSimpleLibrary2.GetList2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssimplelibrary2.getlist2.aspx).

#### Supporting right clicking on a node in Class View

1. Make sure your library capabilities includes [`_LIB_FLAGS2.LF_SUPPORTSLISTREFERENCES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop._lib_flags2.aspx).
2. In your handler for [`IVsSimpleLibrary2.GetList2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssimplelibrary2.getlist2.aspx), you are interested in the case where all of the following are true.

   1. `pobSrch` is a non-null array of length 1. I'll assume the first element is assigned to the local variable `criteria` for the remainder of these conditions.
   2. `criteria.eSrchType == VSOBSEARCHTYPE.SO_ENTIREWORD`
   3. `criteria.grfOptions` has the flag `_VSOBSEARCHOPTIONS.VSOBSO_LOOKINREFS`
   4. `criteria.grfOptions` has the flag `_VSOBSEARCHOPTIONS.VSOBSO_CASESENSITIVE`
3. When the above conditions are met, return an [`IVsSimpleObjectList2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssimpleobjectlist2.aspx) implementation whose children are lazily computed results of a Find All References command.

#### Supporting the Text Editor Command

1. In your `ViewFilter.QueryCommandStatus` implementation, when `guidCmdGroup == VSConstants.GUID_VSStandardCommandSet97` and `nCmdId == VSStd97CmdID.FindReferences` you need to return `OLECMDF.OLECMDF_SUPPORTED | OLECMDF.OLECMDF_ENABLED`.

   - In Visual Studio 2005, note that `nCmdId` will be `VSStd2KCmdID.FindReferences` but the `guidCmdGroup` will be the same as mentioned before. This mismatch was corrected starting in Visual Studio 2008, after which point `VSStd2KCmdID.FindReferences` was no longer used.
2. Override `ViewFilter.HandlePreExec` for the case of the command GUID and ID listed above, and execute the following code for that case:

   ```
   HandleFindReferences();
   return true;
   ```
3. Add the following extension method class:

   ```
   public static class IVsFindSymbolExtensions
   {
       public static void DoSearch(this IVsFindSymbol findSymbol, Guid symbolScope, VSOBSEARCHCRITERIA2 criteria)
       {
           if (findSymbol == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("findSymbol");

           VSOBSEARCHCRITERIA2[] criteriaArray = { criteria };
           ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(findSymbol.DoSearch(ref symbolScope, criteriaArray));
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add the following method to your `ViewFilter` class:

   ```
   public virtual void HandleFindReferences()
   {
       int line;
       int col;

       // Get the caret position
       ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure( TextView.GetCaretPos( out line, out col ) );

       // Get the tip text at that location. 
       Source.BeginParse(line, col, new TokenInfo(), ParseReason.Autos, TextView, HandleFindReferencesResponse);
   }

   // this can be any constant value, it's just used in the next step.
   public const int FindReferencesResults = 100;

   void HandleFindReferencesResponse( ParseRequest req )
   {
       if ( req == null )
           return;

       // make sure the caret hasn't moved
       int line;
       int col;
       ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure( TextView.GetCaretPos( out line, out col ) );
       if ( req.Line != line || req.Col != col )
           return;

       IVsFindSymbol findSymbol = CodeWindowManager.LanguageService.GetService(typeof(SVsObjectSearch)) as IVsFindSymbol;
       if ( findSymbol == null )
           return;

       // TODO: calculate references as an IEnumerable<IVsSimpleObjectList2>

       // TODO: set the results on the IVsSimpleLibrary2 (used as described below)

       VSOBSEARCHCRITERIA2 criteria =
           new VSOBSEARCHCRITERIA2()
           {
               dwCustom = FindReferencesResults,
               eSrchType = VSOBSEARCHTYPE.SO_ENTIREWORD,
               grfOptions = (uint)_VSOBSEARCHOPTIONS2.VSOBSO_LISTREFERENCES,
               pIVsNavInfo = null,
               szName = "Find All References"
           };

       findSymbol.DoSearch(new Guid(SymbolScopeGuids80.All), criteria);
   }
   ```
5. Update your implementation of [`IVsSimpleLibrary2.GetList2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssimplelibrary2.aspx). When the search criteria's `dwCustom` value is set to `FindReferencesResults`, rather than compute the results of a Find All References command on a Class View or Object Browser node, you only need to return an [`IVsSimpleObjectList2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssimpleobjectlist2.aspx) that wraps the results previously calculated by your `HandleFindReferencesResponse` method.

Comment: I will give this a try tomorrow and let you know how it turns out.  Thank you for such a detailed answer!  I was not expecting any answers at all this quickly.

Comment: @JonSenchyna Please let me know if I made an error, rather than edit this post. My library uses extension methods in many places and sometimes I miss them. I added the `DoSearch` extension method which handles the array issue and also allows passing the `Guid` by value instead of with `ref`.

Comment: My apologies; thanks for cleaning that up.  Do you have any good references or examples on implementing the `IVsSimpleObjectList2` interface?  I'm making quite a bit of progress, but it's been a lot of trial-and-error.

Comment: Actually, I think I found a good starting point.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Ah, `dwCustom` was the missing piece for me. I was starting to lose hope that there was a way to populate the list manually :-) Thanks for this super detailed answer! (I'm used to much more sparse documentation on VS guts.)

Comment: Is there a way to filter down to the selected file, or even certain extensions?  I have a language service for a proprietary scripting language.  We typically have some of these scripts included as embedded resources in normal C# projects.  Finding references takes forever when I have the solution loaded, but is very quick when I only have the file open.